# Dynamically assign values to lightning progress bar

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have an object whose child records are getting created dynamically from api response. From the records I am creating different metadata like input-text, combobox, multi picklist etc in a custom lwc. I am trying to capture number of fields which are filled with values and displaying it in progress bar the percentage

https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/eURvPTqiAHUVsCyKuYXF/src/app.html?p=stories

[image]

The problem i am facing here is when filling the first field only i am getting the percentage on the progress bar. Filling next and third one is not incrementing the percentage . Like in the above case it should be 100%.

Here i cant take field names in the query selector and check , as this is frequently changing by api response. How to store the percentage for each row and at the end submit it to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, you're checking if the currently modified input has a name. This always turns out to be true, resulting in a value of 1, which in turn calculates a value of 1/this.arr.length, which is always 33.33...% in the given code.

Instead, grab all your inputs, and check to see if they have a value.

```
  handleInputValueChanged(e) {
    let count = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')]
      .reduce((p,v) => (p+(v.value!==''?1:0)), 0);
    let val = (count/this.arr.length) * 100;
    this.value = val;
  }
```

Where `reduce` passes in a "previous value" and a "current value", where we can count how many entries have a value.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/OLEfTVuq12vvkhN8rxNY/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: Hi sfdcfox.. as always u r the champ .. is there any way to make it generic like without using this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input'). because from api response  i can get any data type . What will happen if i have a 2-3 input fields, 1-2 text area fields , picklist and multi picklist fields

Comment: @sfdc_to_learn You can query using most [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), so you can query individual elements using commas (e.g. `querySelectorAll('lightning-input,lightning-select,lightning-combobox')` or with a common class (e.g. `querySelectorAll('.input')`).